# Import UTF-8 CSV FILES by using ADO.net（OLEDB）

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv, utf-8

I use this code to import a text file(.CSV) ，but when this file is created by UTF-8 code , it can not be success.  Only I save as ANSI code （using Note.exe）, it can be OK.

```
Function getDataset(ByVal sql As String, ByVal path As String) As DataSet
    'Try
    'Dim connstr As String = GetINI("Setting", "cString",     "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\DataSouce\DataBase.mdb", Application.StartupPath & "\setting.ini")
    Dim connstr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & path & "\;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connstr)                   '("provider=microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & CurDir() & "\data.mdb")
    Dim adapter1 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
    Dim commandBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter1)
    getDataset = New DataSet
    adapter1.Fill(getDataset, "temp")
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    'End Try

 End Function
```

I even try to build a schema.ini like this, is not ok either

```
[temp.CSV]
Format=Delimited(,)
ColNameHeader=false
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet= ANSI  
 （or  UTF-8 ）
```

Comment: The valid values for `CharacterSet=` are `CharacterSet=ANSI` and `CharacterSet=OEM`. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I have tried both of these ，ANSI will get the wrong Character when it isn't english. oem will get no field error .  what's OEM means?

Comment: You should better use 3rd party CSV parsers, they are a lot faster than OleDB, and give more control to you as a developer.

Comment: For example? what parsers is better (just like use sql to query)? and for free

Answer (score 0):

VB has a built in csv parser. Check out this article: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/.

TextFieldParser is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace.  You will have to import it if you are building your module in C#.